# How to choose a file on client or server from a web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-server, explorer

I currently am trying to write an application that displays a set of information. The user schould be able to choose a file which is on the server
so that the information in the file can be send to the client to be displayed.
I know where the possible files are stored and would like to do something like opening the Explorer so that the user can choose which file he wants. I get that opening the Explorer on Clientside is an issue for securety reasons and I can´t really see how something like that would be able on serverside.

So my question:

Is there a way to open the explorer on server or clientside so that the user of my asp.net mvc application can choose a file that than will be displayed?

Comment: You need to show your code. There is no reason to reload the whole table (your dialog contains the values you edit, so just use those to update the existing row) and in anycase you would need to use event delegation for the button click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by sending a List of all possible files to the client. There the client can choose the one he wants and send it back to the server
so that the server can send back the file to be displayed.